# How to extract values from MySQL query in Ansible play

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, ansible

In an Ansible play, I'm running a successful SQL query on a MySQL database which returns:

```
"result": [
        {
            "account_profile": "sbx"
        },
        {
            "account_profile": "dev"
        }
    ]
```

That result is saved into a variable called query_output.  I know that I can display the results array in Ansible via

```
- debug:
    var: query_output.result
```

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to extract the 2 account_profile values.

My end goal is to extract them into a fact which is an array.  Something like:

```
"aws_account_profiles": [ "sbx", "dev" ]
```

I know that I'm missing something really obvious.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you want is the [`map` filter's `attribute=` usage](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#map):

`{{ query_output.result | map(attribute="account_profile") | list }}`

Comment: I'm glad it was something simple. Please mark the answer as accepted, so others will know that it helped you